# How Can I pass the value of select list to a form by url?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-forms

I am trying to send a value of select list with the form URL with the following HTML markup.

```
<select class="form-select" name="field_with_contact[und]" id="edit-field-with-contact-und"><option value="_none">- None -</option><option value="26">Rawhi Pharmacy</option></select>
```

The form URL is http://www.example.com/node/add/deal.

How can I send the value 26 to the form?

Thank you

Comment: what do mean "send the value to the form"? Do you mean submit the value to the server? Do you mean submit the value via the querystring?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Prepopulate](http://drupal.org/project/prepopulate) module which is thought for exactly this purpose.

As shown in the project page, a URL like `http://example.com/node/add/blog?edit[title]=this%20is%20the%20title` would pre-populate the title with *this is the title*.

The module can be used with every form, and it has an official release that is used (on August 6, 2017) from [5004 sites](http://drupal.org/project/usage/prepopulate).

Before January 1, 2013, the usage of the module was the following.

> [image: screenshot]

As of August 18, 2017, the usage of the module for Drupal 6 decreased, since Drupal 6 is not officially supported anymore, but the total usage slightly increased thanks to its usage in Drupal 7 and Drupal 8 sites.

> [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

If you go to "www.mysite.com/node/add/deal/26" the following code will print The number passed in url was: 26

Here is the code:

```
function my_module_menu()
{
    $items = array();


    $items['node/add/deal/%'] = array(
        'title'           => 'Add deal',
        'page callback'   => 'drupal_get_form',
        'page arguments'  => array('node_add_deal_form', 3),
        'access callback' => array(TRUE),
        'type'            => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );

    return $items;
}

function node_add_deal_form($form, &$form_state, $number)
{
    $form = array();

    $form['number'] = array(
        '#markup' => '<p>The number passed in url was: '. $number. '</p>',
    );

    return $form;
}
```